# using pgpool, i got empty value in replication state

Tags: postgresql, pgpool, postgresql-14

I'm trying to use pgpool to postgres HA.

node_id | hostname | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_bala
nce_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+----------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+----------
---------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
0       | master   | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | primary | 1          | false
| 0                 |                   |                        | 2022-05-30 10:33:21
1       | slave    | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | standby | primary | 0          | true
| 419431440         |                   |                        | 2022-05-30 10:33:21

In this process, other process is working well, but I got empty value replictation_state and replication_sync_state.
And I got high value in replication_delay.

Why those values are empty and high value?

Is there should change values in postgres.conf or pgpool.conf for replication?

In this case, I used 'pg_basebackup -h host -U Repuser -p port -D dir -X stream' for slave

this is pcp_node_info's result
master 5432 2 0.500000 up up primary primary 0 none none 2022-05-30 10:42:40
slave 5432 2 0.500000 up up standby primary 419431848 none none 2022-05-30 10:42:40

Sorry to my English Level, Thank you for your help

My version

- postgres 14.2
- pgpool 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide **application_name** in both configurations files - **postgresql.conf** (primary_conninfo variable) and **pgpool.conf** for each node.

Also you should check **recovery_1st_stage** and **follow_primary.sh** files as there you also find block with application_name. Script are used by pgpool to recover replica (with pcp_recover_node) or promote new master.

After all you can check current value with "*select * from pg_stat_replication;*" (on master) or "*select * from pg_stat_wal_receiver;*" (on replica)

More information: https://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-4.3.1/en/html/example-cluster.html